# ffmpeg: Continiously encode and append base64 data chunks into output file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, video-processing

I have a `.mov` file thats being written into by my iphone cam saved as `input.mov` and I have a script that's reading the currently updating file and I am trying to encode the video and audio codec into a `.mkv` container.

I have little knowledge of this tool, but looking at similar Q/A's around `ffmpeg` usage I have found little on using base64 as input. But it is [documented](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#data) by ffmpeg for images, so I assume it is possible and I have also used `data:video/mp4` since these file types are very similar.

I have:

```
const ifRecordingStream = await fs.readStream('input.mov', 'base64', 4095);
ifRecordingStream.open();

ifRecordingStream.onData((chunk) => 
    execute(`ffmpeg -f concat -i "data:video/mp4;base64,${chunk} -c:v h264 -c:a aac output.mkv")
);
```

`onData()` currently throws `Line {}: unknown keyword {}`

Is my command wrong?

`ffmpeg -f concat -i "data:video/mp4;base64,${chunk}" -c:v h264 -c:a aac output.mkv`

Any help at all is welcomed.

Comment: I want to do something similar, if you got a solution do tell it.

Comment: It's very not clear if .mov's can be "streamed" to another file in realtime tho...

Answer (score 0):

It maybe help you:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -f image2pipe -i pipe: -i <AUDIO FILE> -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -profile main -qp 1 -shortest -movflags +faststart -tune animation <OUTPUTFILE>
```

https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-July/027528.html